# How to use the elements in one matrix to identify multiple elements in second matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have two matrices. I need to find the coefficient alpha of the elements in the second matrix based on whether a participant meets a condition in the first matrix. For example, for all the elements that  are 1 in the first matrix:

```
[1,1]   #participant 1 in 2008

[3,1]   #participant 3 in 2008

[2,2]   #participant 2 in 2009

[3,2]   #participant 3 in 2009
```

I need to find the coefficient alpha for the all corresponding elements in matrix 2 or in this example, one coefficient alpha of all of the following elements:

```
[1,1:3]    #2008 elements for participant 1

[3,1:3]    #2008 elements for participant 3

[2,4:6]    #2009 elements for participant 2

[3,4:6]    #2009 elements for participant 3


my_vector_1<-c(1,2,1,4,1,1,7,8,2,4,5,6,10,11,2)

my_matrix_1<-matrix(data=my_vector_1, nrow=3, ncol=5)

my_matrix_1

colnames(my_matrix_1)<-c(paste0("Y", 2008:2012))

rownames(my_matrix_1)<-c(paste0("Participant", 1:3))

my_vector_2<-c(2,4,6,8,10,11,12,13,14,16,2,12,3,14,5,12,7,18,9,22,12,13,14,15,8,9,10)

my_matrix_2<-matrix(data=my_vector_2, nrow=3, ncol=9)

colnames(my_matrix_2)<-c("O2008", "Q2008", "R2008", "O2009", "Q2009", "R2009", "O2010", "Q2010", "R2010")

rownames(my_matrix_2)<-c(paste0("Participant", 1:3))

my_matrix_2
```

Answer (score 0):

We could first find out all the row/column position where `my_matrix_1 == 1`. Use row index to subset row from `my_matrix_2` and manipulate column index to get 3 column from each.

```
n <- 3
mat <- which(my_matrix_1 == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) my_matrix_2[x[1], (n * (x[2] - 1) + 1) : (n * x[2])]))

#             [,1] [,2] [,3]
#Participant1    2    8   12
#Participant3    6   11   14
#Participant2    2   14    7
#Participant3   12    5   18
```